# Multi-level menu tree

Tags: php

I want to make a menu not limited level, I have an array

```
$menu = [
 0 => [
   'id' => 1,
   'parent_id' => 0,
   'title' => 'Category 1',
 ],
 2 => [
   'id' => 2
   'parent_id' => 0,
   'title' => 'Category 2',
 ],
 3 => [
   'id' => 3,
   'parent_id' => 2,
   'title' => 'Category 3',
 ],
 4 => [
   'id' => 4,
   'parent_id' => 3,
   'title' => 'Category 4',
 ]
]
```

And I want to get a structure something like this:

```
$tree = [
 0 => [
   'id' => 1,
   'parent_id' => 0,
   'title' => 'Category 1'
 ],
 2 => [
   'id' => 2
   'parent_id' => 0,
   'title' => 'Category 2',
   'child' => [
     0 => [
      'id' => 3,
      'parent_id' => 2,
      'title' => 'Category 3',
        'child' => [
           1 => [
           'id' => 4,
           'parent_id' => 3,
           'title' => 'Category 4',
           ]
         ]
    ]
   ]
 ]
]
```

I wrote some code, but it works up to a maximum of the second level of nesting,at the third level, problems begin

```
$tree = [];
        foreach ($menu as $node) {
            if (!$node['parent_id']) {
                $tree[$node['id']] = $node;
            }
            else {
                $tree[$node['parent_id']]['children'][$node['id']] = $node;
            }
        }
        return $tree;
```

I didn't seem to find anything, maybe I was looking badly

Comment: Doesn't menu item 4 have menu item 2 as a parent, instead of menu item 3?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, sorry, I made mistake

Comment: The key phrase you’re looking for is “recursive function”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you going:

```php
function appendItem(array &$haystack, array $toAppend): void
{
    foreach ($haystack as &$menuItem) {
        if ($menuItem['id'] === $toAppend['parent_id']) {
            if (array_key_exists('child', $menuItem)) {
                $menuItem['child'][] = $toAppend;
            } else {
                $menuItem['child'] = [$toAppend];
            }
            return;
        } 
        if (array_key_exists('child', $menuItem)) {
            appendItem($menuItem['child'], $toAppend);
        }
    }
}

foreach ($menu as $key => $menuItem) {
    if ($menuItem['parent_id'] !== 0) {
        unset($menu[$key]);
        appendItem($menu, $menuItem);
    }
}
```

The function basically traverses over an array and if it finds an element where the `parent_id` of the `toAppend` matches the `id` of the element in the loop, it will be added of a child of that item. If not, it will repeat the function over it's `child` array (if it exists).

Some optimisations might be done to this, but it's a good start. [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/TdcFc) to see the code in action.